# How do I remove version number from file path? - Winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, filepath

I am wondering how to remove the version number from a file path in a Windows Form Application.

Currently I wish to save some users application data to a .xml file located in the roaming user profile settings.

To do this I use:

```
get
{
     return Application.UserAppDataPath + "\\FileName.xml";
}
```

However this returns the following string:

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\folder\subfolder\1.0.0.0\FileName.xml`

and I was wondering if there is a non-hack way to remove the version number from the file path so the file path looks like this:

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\folder\subfolder\FileName.xml`

Besides parsing the string looking for the last "\", I do not know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.userappdatapath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it always returns the path *Base Path\CompanyName\ProductName\ProductVersion*. So you could do `UserAppDataPath + "..\FileName.xml"`. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Directory.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for this purpose.

```
get
{
    var dir = Directory.GetParent(Application.UserAppDataPath);
    return Path.Combine(dir.FullName, "FileName.xml");
}
```

Also note that I've used [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of concatenating paths, this method helps you to avoid so many problems. Never concatenate strings to create path.

Comment: Thanks alot @sriram Sakthivel, exactly what I was looking for.